# novice user needs assistance for three peltiers being connected to a single power source

Tags: camera, peltier

I am a novice user, and I am not very familier with Peltier setups, for my old CCD astonomy camera. The Peltier that was broken in the camera is not supplied by the manufacturer anymore, nor will they renovate such an old camera, so I hope that someone can help me out. I am familier with soldering wires together, and I have now purchased three Peltier units that can fit in the small space where the broken Peltier used to sit.

The Power source that runs this old broken Peltier is a 12 Volt DC, and the amps for this system is 3A.

The Peltiers are not to be connected with each other in a serial connection, but the wires from each Peltier unit is to be connected in a common joint with the wire that comes from the circuit board. Can I connect the three Peltiers, each running on 4 Volt DC and by 1 Amp, and then have them work together like they were one Peltier?

I am unsure what the physics will work like during such a setup, so just wanting to be sure, as not to damage the connection in the circuit board, before trying.

Comment: Wiring peltiers in parallel (from what I understand you're wanting to do) is very common, then these run at the same voltage and pull some current as defined by their physical properties. My worry is whether or not you matched the old broken peltier parameters with the new ones. You should match them as closely as possible. Can you provide the model# of the old peltier and the model# of the new peltiers?

Comment: Hi Jarrod. I have removed the original peltier and it is now utterly destroyed. Nothing was written on the surface of the original surfaces of the ceramic sides when I removed it. So it is not to be determined by any manufacturing company, so I am really at a lost here. However I have configured a different way of cooling my peltier, by adding a heatsink in a way than what is originally designed. I wouls like to send you a drawing on mail, will you be willing to help me out by letting me write you?

Comment: We’re here to help. Though if you can, edit your question with the drawing so others can try and help as well. Though without the original specs it’s hard to say how well the new one will match in performance.

Comment: Hi Jarrod. Thanks, I appreciate it. I cannot seem to find a way to share any drawing I make on this site here? How do I do that?

Comment: If you click edit on your question then click on the image icon, it will popup an image upload form so you can upload your image to your question.

Comment: Type number ：TEC4-24603
Dimensions ： 15x15mm and 20x20mm and 30x30mm and 40x40mm in a four Layer design.Thickness:13.6mm(±0.1mm)
△TmaxQC=0(C) ：≥107°C
U=standard(V) ：14.6V ,I=standard(A) ：3A
Qcmax △T=0(W) ：6.8 W

Comment: The info I just wrote before, is a four stage Peltier that I would like to know in what temperature range it could perhaps work, with regards to freezing temperature?For example if I am to use a 200gram fan cooled heatsink in the setup.

Comment: The weight of the heatsink used to cool the hot side doesn't tell me the thermal dissipation of that heatsink, so I can't really help you there. In regards to the TEC itself, the Qmax is only 6.8W in an ideal situation, reality will be less. The result is that if you take 3 of them in parallel you'll be drawing 9A at 12V, which exceeds your power supplies current draw from what you provided. If you do it is series, you'll draw less amperage and they will create less waste heat... but then I'm not confident it will cool well enough.

Comment: Mainly you need to find out what the thermal load is from the part you're trying to cool, or find out what the original pletier and replicate it's parameters with a new peltier. Otherwise you're just shooting in the dark, and could either kill your power supply by trying to draw too much current, or have your part you're trying to cool overheat and maybe become damaged from the heat.

Comment: Hi again. I am unsure about what you mean by thermal load...is it the temperature the original setting is with regards to cooling of the sensor? I know that the original Peltier was designed to cool down the sensor at 20 degrees Celsius below ambient temperature. And since the camera itself is powered by a 12V DC 1.5A power station/outlet, perhaps the Peltier can work at the approx. Amperage as well...?

Comment: Maybe 1A since some electricity needs to work the circuit boards and a mechanical motor type sensor shutter. I have seen the software in use, and it is possible to set the peltier cooling to -40 degrees Celsius below ambient, but as I wrote the TEC system only states that it can run at a -20 degree Celsius below ambient temperature. I have purchased a Peltier controller aparatus that can connect cooling fans and Peltier device to it, and then it is able to cool down the Peltier while measuring the temperature with a temperature probe, which is to be connected to the sensor backside if possible

Comment: And when I mean that the TEC system is stated to work at that given temperature, this is because it is what the manufacturer has written in the workbook that came with the camera. It does not describe however, what the TEC system is using for voltage and current.

Comment: My idea is basically to use the before mentioned purchased Peltier controller to try and make an alternative system that works for itself, and is not to be connected to the circuit board of the camera, and hence not the TEC software that would control the original Peltier in camera. So I am currently not trying to find out a replacement Peltier for the original, but one that works at somewhat the same electrics criteria as the original, and that can be controlled at a distance, which will incorporate some long cables between the external purchased Peltier control. and the camera sensor system.

Comment: I found some more data regarding the Kodak KAI-10100 Color Sensor´s physics testing: Description Symbol Minimum Maximum Units Notes
Operating Temperature TOP -50 70 °C 1
Humidity RH 5 90 % 2
Output Bias Current Iout 0.0 -40 mA 3
Off-chip Load CL 10 pF

Comment: and this: DC Bias Operating Conditions
Description Symbol Minimum Nominal Maximum Units Maximum DC
Current (mA) Notes
Output Gate OG -3.0 -2.5 -2.0 V 1 µA
Reset Drain RD 10.5 11.5 11.5 V 1 µA
Output Amplifier Supply VDD 14.5 15.0 15.5 V 2 mA
Ground GND 0.0 0.0 0.0 V
Substrate SUB 8.0 TBD 17.0 V 1
ESD Protection ESD -9.0 -8.0 -7.0 V 2
Output Bias Current Iout -5 -10 mA 3

Comment: As I can see from the first data, the minimum working temperature is -50 degrees Celsius, and the maximum is 70 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Perhaps the above written is somewhat confusing as it has been copied from a schematic. The site I have found the physical data is: https://www.pco.de/fileadmin/user_upload/db/download/KAI-11000CMLongSpec.pdf. I hope this can help. Regards. Jan

Comment: My suggestion would be to get either the peltier model# from the camera manufacturer or see if they have the specs, mentioning that you will do the repair even if they don't service it anymore. This will allow you to get a replacement part without having to worry about the engineering end.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help more. Initially it seemed like an easy question, but the more we delve into it the more I realized some engineering will need to be done since you don't have the original part#. However, if you're not familiar with this end, it can be difficult and risky. I assume this camera is expensive so I don't wish to provide advice that may result in a device failure.

Comment: Hi again, well actually you have been a great help! The camera is an old type that the manufacturer Celestron produced some 7 years ago. From new it costed some 2000 dollars, but I got it used by a person on ebay, for the mere sum of 300 dollars. Celestron have now discontinued the camera a couple of years ago, and they do not offer any kind of technical assistance or repair at all. They made that very clear to me... I will try to figure out experimentially how to create a cooling system that is external.

Comment: If I can figure out to make an alternative setup, but still need some light assistance regarding other electrical issues with the camera, can I then contact you again? You have helped quite a bit! And I appreciate it! Regards. Jan